# What is the correct way to initialize a variable in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, curly-braces, list-initialization

I have the following code :

```
bool c (a == b);
```

and

```
bool c {a == b};
```

where a and b are some variables of same type.

I want to know that, what is the difference in above two initializations and which one should be preferred in what conditions ? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both forms are [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

Using curly braces `{}` for initialization checks for narrowing conversions and generates an error if such a conversion happens. Unlike `()`. ([gcc issues a warning by default](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783) and needs `-Werror=narrowing` compiler option to generate an error when narrowing occurs.)

Another use of curly braces `{}` is for *uniform initialization*: initialize both types with and without constructors using the same syntax, e.g.:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
T create(Args&&... args) {
    T value{std::forward<Args>(args)...}; // <--- uniform initialization + perfect forwarding
    return value;
}

struct X { int a, b; };
struct Y { Y(int, int, int); };

int main() {
    auto x = create<X>(1, 2);    // POD
    auto y = create<Y>(1, 2, 3); // A class with a constructor.
    auto z = create<int>(1);     // built-in type
}
```

The only drawback of using curly braces `{}` for initialization is its interaction with `auto` keyword. `auto` deduces `{}` as `std::initializer_list`, which is a known issue, see ["Auto and braced-init-lists"](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html).

Comment: So, in this case, it shouldn't matter what we use ? While in cases where we do long to int or whenever there are chances of data loss, it should throw an exception / error ?

Comment: @cruskal if `==` is overloaded to return something other than `bool`, `{}` will generate an error.

Comment: Also, beware of braced initializers being matched to `std::initializer_list` in constructors, e.g `std::vector<int> c{a,b}` vs `std::vector<int> c(a,b)`

Comment: @juanchopanza It is a known gcc bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yes, i did not think about that, and what should be preferred way while writing a program ?

Comment: @cruskal Prefer using stricter options if possible.

Answer (score 3):

First one is the C++03 style direct initialization.
The second is C++11 style direct initialization, it additionally checks for narrowing conversions. Herb Sutter recommends the following in new code:

```
auto c = <expression>;
```

or when you want to commit to specific type T:

```
auto c = T{<expression>};
```

One known drawback with curly braces when T is some class with overloaded constructor, where one constructor gets std::initializer_list as parameter, std::vector for example:

```
auto v = std::vector<int>{10}; // create vector<int> with one element = 10
auto v = std::vector<int>(10); // create vector<int> with 10 integer elements
```

Comment: The second one is such a silly recommendation. What does it gain you? The only thing it does is impose more constraints on `T`.

Comment: @juanchopanza The reasoning from Sutter's original article is: `Consider declaring local variables auto x = type{ expr }; when you do want to explicitly commit to a type. It is self-documenting to show that the code is explicitly requesting a conversion, it guarantees the variable will be initialized, and it won’t allow an accidental implicit narrowing conversion. Only when you do want explicit narrowing, use ( ) instead of { }.`

Comment: Although even he goes on to say: `The jury is still out on whether to recommend this one wholesale, as we’re still trying it out, but it does offer some advantages and I suggest you try it out for a while and see if it works well for you.`

Comment: `T x{expr}` is still shorter to type and read than `auto x = T{expr}`.

Comment: @TartanLlama That (the first quote) sounds like nonsense. `T x{expr};` commits you to a type and is as self-documenting as the `auto` version. And it does not require an available copy constructor.

Comment: Also, that is Herb Sutter, not Scott Meyers.

Comment: @juanchopanza The self-documentation comment is referring to the difference between the `auto x = T{expr}` and `auto x = expr` constructs. But I agree with you, I'm just playing devils advocate; it seems like going overboard on `auto` usage for the sake of it.

Comment: @juanchopanza There is also a consistency argument. If you have a bunch of initializations, some where you want to track type and some where you want to commit to a specific type there is an argument that it is easier to read if they consistently use `auto`.

Answer (score 2):

Now we have five forms of initializations. They are

```
T x = expression;
T x = ( expression );
T x (  expression );
T x = { expression };
T x { expression };
```

Each of the forms has its own peculirities. :)

For example let's assume that you have the following declarations in the global namespace

```
int x;

void f( int x ) { ::x = x; }
int g() { return x ; }
long h() { return x; }
```

then in main you can write

```
int main()
{
    int x ( g() );
}
```

This code will compile successfully.

However a programmer by mistake made a typo

```
int main()
{
    int x; ( g() );
         ^^
}
```

Oops! This code also compiles successfully.:)

But if the programmer would write

```
int main()
{
    int x = ( g() );
}
```

and then make a typo

```
int main()
{
    int x; = ( g() );
         ^^
}
```

then in this case the code will not compile.

Well let's assume that the programmer decided at first to set a new value for the global variable x before initializing the local variable.

So he wrote

```
int main()
{
    int x ( f( 10 ), g() );
}
```

But this code does not compile!

Let's insert equality sign

```
int main()
{
    int x = ( f( 10 ), g() );
}
```

Now the code compiles successfully!

And what about braces?

Neither this code

```
int main()
{
    int x { f( 10 ), g() };
}
```

nor this code

```
int main()
{
    int x = { f( 10 ), g() };
}
```

compiles!:)

Now the programmer decided to use function h(), He wrote

```
int main()
{
    int x ( h() );
}
```

and his code compiles successfully. But after a time he decided to use braces

```
int main()
{
    int x { h() };
}
```

Oops! His compiler issues an error

> error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'long' to
> 'int' in initializer list

The program decided to use type specifier auto. He tried two approaches

```
int main()
{
    auto x { 10 };
    x = 20;
}
```

and

```
int main()    
{
    auto x = { 10 };
    x = 20;
}
```

and ...some compilers compiled the first program but did not compile the second program and some compilers did not compile the both programs.:)

And what about using `decltype`?

For example the programmer wrote

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };
    decltype( auto ) b = a;
}
```

And his compiler issued an error!

But when the programmer enclosed a in parentheses like this

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };
    decltype( auto ) b = ( a );
}
```

the code compiled successfully!:)

Now the programmer decided to learn OOP. He wrote a simple class

```
struct Int
{
    Int( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
};
    
int main()
{
    Int x = { 10 };    
}
```

and his code compiles successfully.
But the programmer has known that there is function specifier `explicit` and he has decided to use it

```
struct Int
{
    explicit Int( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
};
    
int main()
{
    Int x = { 10 };    
}
```

Oops! His compiler issued an error

```
error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
```

The programmer decided to remove the assignment sign

```
struct Int
{
    explicit Int( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
};
    
int main()
{
    Int x { 10 };    
}
```

and his code compiled successfully!:)